# Controlling speaker that has 4 interconnected pins

Tags: speakers

I am fairly new to and interested in electronic engineering. I want to control a speaker I found in an Xbox 360 headset with my Arduino, but I dont know how. Other small speakers I own all have 2 pins, + and -. But this speaker has 4 pins which are all interconnected. Image of the speaker:

[image]

Can someone tell me how this speaker works, or put me on the right track?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I couldn't get that picture to work. It just wouldn't show up..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the left hand pair are connected together and ditto the right hand pair: -

[image]

I've shown red lines where I believe copper exists joining pairs of connections. You should use a meter to confirm this or, with an amplifier output fed via 100 ohms to protect it from shorting, experiment with which connection produces sound from the speaker.

Comment: All pins are connected to eachother. If I number the pins 1 to 4 (left to right) pin 1 & 3, 1 & 4, 2 & 3, 2 & 4 make a sound. pin 1 & 2, 3 & 4 shortcircuit.

Comment: @EmielSteerneman then it is as I thought. Use the outer pins (1 and 4) to make a connection is my recommendation. The inner pins are probably soldered connections to the speaker cone coil and should be left alone - you might be able to see small wires connected to these pins that enter the body of the speaker. The picture isn't detailed enough for me to see.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like just a junction PCB- two of the pads will be for your wires and two will have the thin wires going to the voice coil (probably the inner two are the ones you're not supposed to use).

You can see the copper connecting the pads together in pairs (kind of inverted u's).